# How do I make a discord.js random number generator that generates off user input

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

How do I make a discord.js random number generator that generates off user input? I've been trying to do this for a long time but just cant get anything to work with my format of code.

```js
if (message.content == "<lottery") {
   let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
       .setTitle("**Lottery Winner!**")
       .setDescription("The winner of the lottery's number is {The random number that is generated}")
       .setColor("RANDOM")
       .setFooter(`Congratulations!`)
 
       .setThumbnail('https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/800757031506149426/835360163782459422/OIP.png')
   message.channel.send(embed);
}
```

How do I somehow get the range inside that embed?

Answer (score 0):

This should work for random number

```js
//Define this function somewhere in the code.
const RandomInt = (min, max) => { //Generates a random integer number
  return( Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) ) + min );
}

//Then
if (message.content.startsWith("<lottery")){
    const args = message.content.slice("<lottery".length).split(" ");
    // args is the arguments aka input passed by the user
    if(!args.length){
        //not enough input
        return message.reply("Not enough input")
    }
    if(!parseInt(args[0])){
        //Invalid input
        return message.reply("Invalid input - Give a number input")
    }
    let Winner = RandomInt(1, parseInt(args[0]));
    let emb = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        //put the title and others
        .setDescription(`The winning number is ${Winner}. Congratulations`)
        //The footer and rest
    message.channel.send(emb);
}
```

This should work

Comment: There are a few things wrong with your code. First of all `return` is not a function, so `return(message.reply())` should be `return message.reply()`. Second of all, you didn't use a keyword such as `let` or `const` when defining `RandomInt`, which is bad practice and will result in an error in strict mode. Third of all, you're using `let` when the variable isn't reassigned. Overall, it would be nice if you also added some explanation outside of the code block to what you're doing, such as: what are `args`? how does `RandomInt()` work? etc

Comment: If you have ever code with Javascript you know `return()`, `return` and `return((((( )))))` are basically the same. Second "I don't need to define `let` or `const` while defining a function Javascript does it for me (It's not Java) Third everyone working with `discord.js` should know about `args`. Anyway, I'll fix em

Comment: First, ....but why though? Second, ....but why though? Third, fair point, but it's nice just in case

Comment: First I used to code C++ and there was `return(69)` so it looks weird to use `return 69` now. Second I fixed it. Third I fixed it